# How can I write a Circular Log script in Perl?

Tags: perl, logging

we are trying to write a script in Perl that makes a circular log. One program generates a really big log file and we want to separate it into 5,6 or so files.

```
use Log::Dispatch::FileRotate;

  my $file = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate->new( name      => 'file1',
                                       min_level => 'info',
                                       filename  => 'C:\Test\Log.txt',
                                       dir => 'C:\Test',
                                       mode      => 'write' ,
                                       size      => 5,
                                       max       => 6,
                                      );


    $file->log( level => 'info', message => 'Comment');
```

We found this code online, but it's behaving a bit erratically. Is this script supposed to write a new file whenever the main log file grows by 5MB and into 6 files tops? How can we accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the documentation for Log::Dispatch::FileRotate? It's on CPAN.

Comment: Yes that's the first thing we tried. The example is from their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code, and think `size` is in bytes, so if you want to write 5MB logs you need to set size to `5*1024*1024` or something like this. My test code, that writes 6 files 5MB each:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Dispatch::FileRotate;

my $file = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate->new(
                                            name => 'file1',
                                            min_level => 'info',
                                            filename  => '/tmp/log/some.log',
                                            mode => 'append',
                                            size => 5*1024*1024,
                                            max => 6,
                                            newline => 1
                                          );

while (1) {
        $file->log( level => 'info', message => time );
        $file->log( level => 'debug', message => time." debug ".time ); #this will not be logged, because of log level
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, it was very helpful. Do you think that there's a method that can specify where to copy the log files, like dir 'some path'  ?

Comment: i see no such options in this module. it always copyes rotated logs in the same dir with original log. you can use other logging modules if you realy need this, for example Logfile::Rotate, as Borodin says in his answer

Comment: Hi, do you if it's possible to use something like
move($file,"temp\Logs\"); 
We modified your code a bit, and we got exactly what we were looking for. However since we're still testing we don't know where the target log file will be located, that's why we'd try to fix it from here and automatically place logs into seperate dir. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use something like [`Log::Rolling`](https://metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aRolling) or [`Logfile::Rotate`](https://metacpan.org/module/Logfile%3a%3aRotate).

Both of these modules are ready-built solutions to your problem and hopefully have all the bugs already ironed out.